# Как сделать подобный счётчик голосов?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

mail.ru вкрутило интерсный счётчик голосов ...
у меня лично сам по себе счётчик сделать не проблема вот к примеру:

```js
document.querySelector('.number').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.cnt').textContent++;
}
```

```css
.number {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: ;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.number span {
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="number">
  <span class="emodji">
    
  </span>
  <span>+<span/>
  <span class="cnt">
   1  
  </span>
</div>
```

Но вопрос не в самом счётчике а вот как они сделали анимацию подсчёта голосов

Вот скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот где я это увидел: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/218215728

**Как можно сделать подобную анимацию ?**

Comment: имеется ввиду анимация цифр `1-2`  ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну да ..круто же ...как буд то слайдер какой то ..и можно отменить ...тоже будет анимация

Comment: У них это вероятно реализовано на VueJS (так плагин показывает) https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html. В примерах и ссылки на библиотеки может найдете - это типа http://velocityjs.org/

Comment: @MaximLensky такая штука называется одометр :) Можно в эту сторону гуглить)

Comment: @k0mar что то похоже ...хм

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg у них там не вью а раньще был ангуляр потом они перешли на другую библиотеку

Comment: @MaximLensky, только что посмотрел прямо на эту кнопку в ОтветахRu, как я и говорил, у нее свойство `__vue__`. Да у меня и плагин на страницах у кого VueJS зеленым загорается.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg хоть убей меня__пересмотрел код и не увидел там _vue_

Comment: @MaximLensky, Как не увидел, да он везде там https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2RD6/Qrmsjccf9

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg хм...действительно ..спс за заметку - не там я смотрел ...я смотрел в теге

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.number span {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.number span, 
.number span div {
  transition: 0.5s
}

.number.like span div {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.number.like span {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="number" onclick="this.classList.toggle('like')">
  <span></span>
  <span><div>1<br>2</div></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Костя а если их там хотя бы 200 будет ?

Comment: Один пользователь может только один лайк поставить, соответственно северная выдача просто должна корректно сформировать компонент, в котором будет текущее число лайков и вторая цифра (+1)

Comment: точно ...я забыл о этом